# drops menu behind table headers when scrolling in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I got a weird issue with IE11. 
When the drop down menu is selected and I begins to scroll,
then the menu drops behind the table headers.

URL of image (sry, don't have enough reputation to post images):

Before Scrolling: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y5MP.png

After Scrolling: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BMzM.png

It only happens in IE11. IE10, Chrome and Firefox all works well.

Thanks in advance.

update: I found this issue only exists in Win8... It works well in Win7....

Answer (score 0):

In the css class / style tag of your drop down add: z-index:9999; and it should be resolved. This is just a rendering issue to do with IE not being explicitly told which element resides at what z index.